# String Iteration Behaviour

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, iterator, iteration

```
var someString = new String('hi');

someString[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  return { // this is the iterator object, returning a single element, the string "bye"
    next: function() {
      if (this._first) {
        this._first = false;
        return { value: 'bye', done: false };
      } else {
        return { done: true };
      }
    },
    _first: true
  };
};
```

This code is for the string iteration behaviour mechanism from MDN but I am unable to understand the usage of the variable `_first`, why it is used, and where it is declared.

Comment: *_first* isn't a variable, it's a property of the *this* object.

Comment: but in console this.first is giving "undefined"

Comment: `this` will refer to different things depending where it is called. Inside the `next` function it will refer to the iterator object, which has a property called `_first` (note the underscore).

Comment: Is this an example provided by MDN? It's a bit string. The fact that you are working with a string object seems irrelevant. You might as well do `var someObject = { [Symbol.iterator]() { ... } };` and get the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code snippet, the iterator object has two properties:

- `next` - a function.
- `_first` - a boolean flag, which is initialized to true.

The `next` function checks `_first` to see if it is the first time the function has been called, and adjusts its behaviour accordingly.

Note that inside the `next` function, `this` will refer to the iterator object, and therefore can be used to access the `_first` property.